# Export multiple array of object in excel as multiple sheets

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have multiple array of object as,

```
const books = [{"book":"harry","part":1},{"book":"harry","part":2},{"book":"harry","part":3}, 
               {"book":"lotr","part":1},{"book":"lotr","part":2}]

const personDetails = [{"name":"ram","age":21},{"name":"jack","age":22},{"name":"ryan","age":45}];
```

I can download for one array of object, by method as,

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

function downloadExcel() {
    const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
    const bookDetails = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(books);
    const wb = { Sheets: { 'BookDet': bookDetails }, SheetNames: ['BookDet'] };
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    const data1 = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data1, "BookDetail Summary.xlsx");
}
```

But how can I export multiple array of object in different sheets in excel. If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Comment: Can you please provide information regarding which libraries you are using? Like FileSaer.js & any else?

Comment: I have added libraries. Could you please have a look now.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating workbook in below manner using `var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();`.

Create worksheets with `XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet` & append both `worksheeet` objects to workbook with `XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet`.

Reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#working-with-the-workbook

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

function downloadExcel() {
    
    /* create a new blank workbook */
    var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

    /* create a worksheet for books */
    var wsBooks = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(books);

    /* Add the worksheet to the workbook */
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, wsBooks, "Books");

    /* create a worksheet for person details */
    var wsPersonDetails = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(personDetails);

    /* Add the worksheet to the workbook */
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, wsPersonDetails, "PersonDetails");
    
    
    const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    const data1 = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data1, "BookDetail Summary.xlsx");    
}
```

Comment: I had one more query related to this question. Can I ask over here only or should I create new question?

Comment: Question is: I want to add a text for each sheet say in sheet1 contains text:" Sheet1" and sheet2 contains text :"sheet2" at top and after that there is table.

Comment: I briefly reviewed documentation from reference but do not found any function which could do so. You can try finding some workaround if possible.

Comment: No Problem. Thank you so much for your time and input. If I am able to find something I will post here  :)